# Parametric question of the curve $x^2 + y^2 + 2x - 4y = 0$?

Tags: parametric

What is the parametric form of the curve above?  If I had to solve it, what I would say is that the first step is to complete the square. However, where would I go from there?

Comment: You have a good first step --- keep going.  How would you parametrize a circle of radius $r$ and center $(h,k)$?

Comment: Not exactly sure. But i know for this question, there is no z-parameter, and therefore it isnt a sphere, but probably a cylinder? Not sure how that helps me though..

Comment: In 2D it is a circle; in 3D a cylinder.  How do you paramatrize a circle of radius $r$ centered at $(0,0)$?

Comment: x=0+t and y=0+t?

Comment: There are various parametrizations. The mot popular one involves trig functions. The parametric equations $x=t$, $y=t$ describe the line $x=y$.

Comment: Hmm.. then x=t^2 and y=t^2?

Comment: That's the first quadrant part of the same line.

Comment: @Nick: It's the second step, so it has something to do with your first step of making the equation a complete square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a rational parametrization using *stereographical projection*, as follows:

The point $(0,0)$ is on the curve. Since the equation is quadratic, for each slope $t$, the line $y=tx$ must intersect the curve at a second point. If you plug $y=tx$ into the equation (and you assume $x\neq 0$), then you should get that the coordinates of the second point of intersection are
$$x=\frac{2(2t-1)}{1+t^2},\quad y=\frac{2t(2t-1)}{1+t^2}.$$
Are those *all* the points on the curve? No, but almost all. If $(x_0,y_0)\neq (0,0)$ is on the curve, then consider the line $L$ from $(0,0)$ to $(x_0,y_0)$:

- If the line $L$ is vertical, then $x_0=0$, and from the equation we have 
  $$y_0^2-4y_0=0$$
  Thus, $y_0=0$ (not allowed, by assumption), or $y_0=4$. Hence $(x_0,y_0)=(0,4)$.
- Otherwise, the line $L$ is not vertical, and $L$ is of the form $y=tx$ and $(x_0,y_0)$ is as given above:
  $$(x_0,y_0)=\left(\frac{2(2t-1)}{1+t^2},\ \frac{2t(2t-1)}{1+t^2}\right).$$

Hence, the points on your curve are 
$$\{(0,4)\}\cup \left\{\left(\frac{2(2t-1)}{1+t^2},\ \frac{2t(2t-1)}{1+t^2}\right): t\in \mathbb{R}\right\},$$
and that's the parametrization we were looking for (notice $(0,0)$ is on the right hand side, with $t=1/2$).

Comment: Why the -1? Any suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 4):

$$x^2 + y^2 + 2x - 4y = 0$$

$$x^2  + 2x +  y^2- 4y = 0$$

$$x^2  + 2x +  1 -1 +y^2- 4y +4 -4= 0$$

$$(x+1)^2 -1 + (y-2)^2-4= 0$$

$$(x+1)^2  + (y-2)^2= 5$$

For a circle with centre at (h,k) and radius r, <del>the</del> a parametric form is $x = h + r\cos(\theta)$ and $y = k + r\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: For those of us who love rational parametrizations, may I suggest "a parametric form" instead of "the parametric form".

Comment: @AndréNicolas Edited. Good Point.